# Sync Android with a website database?

Tags: android, database, synchronization

So this is what I need to do before my traineeship ends.

1. connect android app with the database from a website
2. store some information into the database
3. retrieve some information back from the database

I have already experience with the standard sqlite build in android apps.
The problem is, I need to let people get some information from the server so
they can share information with the others. I have 3 weeks left before I'm
done with my traineeship, so any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Create an SQLite database (Windows GUI SQLite prog: http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)

2) Put it on a server

3) make a php script that will update / read your database (on the server)

```
 <?php

$row_id = $_GET['yourRowId'];
$submitted_var = $_GET['yourUpdateVar'];

if($database = new PDO("sqlite:your_sqlite_database.s3db")){

  //insert data into database
  $query = "UPDATE your_table SET some_field=$submitted_var WHERE _id=$row_id";

  $database->query($query);

  echo DONE;
 } else {
die($err);
 }
?>
```

4) Call this php script from your android app

```
 http://yourserver/yourfolder/yourscript?yourRowId=1&yourUpdateVar=3
 http://yourserver/yourfolder/yourReadScript (parse html response)
```

Done

That's how I'd do it in 3 weeks :-)

OOI were's ur traineeship @?

Comment: My trianeeship is in the Netherlands and I am the only guy who suffers from all the programming work...

Comment: :-) well hope my answer helps

Comment: You made my life much easier, thanx. :)

Comment: Just mark as correct, on the left under the number and arrows, press the tick to make it green :-D

Comment: How can I pm you when I want to ask a question? I will press the arrow button when I'm done. :)

Comment: You can't pm on stackoverflow, I'm available on twitter or anddev.org just see my profile.